# Lisp function with default argument value

Tags: common-lisp

I would like to have a CL function with a single argument, but also with a default argument value.

```
(defun test1 ((x 0))
  (+ x x))
```

would seem to be the syntax, but it doesn't work. The tutorials I'm seeing have the argument-default form like above only in use with &optional and &key. Is it possible to have just one function argument and it with a default?

Comment: What's the purpose of a default, if the parameter is not optional?

Comment: Every positional argument with a default has to be optional or else the default would never be used.

Answer (score 21):

You need to signal that it is an optional argument:

```
(defun test1 (&optional (x 0))
   (+ x x))
```

As written, you have specified an invalid lambda list and should hopefully have seen some diagnostics from the REPL.